# Regular expression for set of all strings containing no 3 consecutive 0s?

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, regular-expressions

The answer is

$1^*01^*01^*+1^*(0+00+\in)1^*$

If I had to rephrase my question, it would be how to approach regular expression problems? Is it all about practice?

How do I understand what the regular expression is doing just like in this case here.

I think I can create DFA for this, but not sure if that would help me to create regular expression(I know there are posts to convert dfa to regular expression but I don't want that hassle).

Comment: $101010101010$ isn't accepted by this regex, for example. But it would be in the language since it doesn't contain $3$ consecutive $0$s.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to go through a DFA (which would definitely be the easiest *systematic* way of doing this), you can approach it by viewing the language as strings of 2, 1 or 0 zeros interleaved by ones:

$$(00 +0 + \epsilon)(1(00 + 0 + \epsilon))^*$$

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26365602/automaton-that-recognizes-a-language-without-3-consecutive-zeros?rq=1 I use this dfa and I got regular expression $(1+01+001)^* + (1+01+001)^*0+(1+01+001)^*0$. I used arden's theorem. Is this also correct?

Comment: @custep It is not since your expression does not accept the string $00$.

Comment: I got it correct. It was typing mistake the last one $(1+01+001)^*00$ Thanks a lot for correction.